# Simplex algorithm experimental complexity

Tags: time-complexity, linear-programming

For a school project I am doing on linear programming, I've implemented the simplex algorithm in Python.

I was hoping to check the complexity on a number of matrices.

Preferably, they would have to be in standard form ($Ax=b$ and $x\geq0$) (or easily put into standard form) and would have to have a finite inf (to avoid the unbounded case). 
Do you have any ideas? Or could you point me torwards a paper or someone who has already done this?

Comment: Answered on cstheory: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16897/test-set-and-benchmarks-for-linear-programming.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't have the right keywords...